# Search Widget - How to determine if "Enter" was pressed or result was selected?

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have a search box which throws up certain auto-suggested values when an address is searched for.

Now there are way ways in which a search event is fired:

1. User starts typing an address (ignores the auto-suggested values) and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd> key
2. User starts typing an address and midway through the process, **selects** a value from the auto-suggested list

In this scenario, is there a way I can figure out whether a selection was made or the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key was pressed in the event handler?

### Javascript

```
var esriMap = new Map("esriMap", {
    basemap: "topo",
    center: [-12.4260, 31.3403],
    zoom: 12
});
var search = new Search({
   map: esriMap,
}, dom.byId("esriSearch"));
search.startup();
search.on("select-result", searchboxResult); // the event handler

function searchboxResult(e)
{
  // determine "Enter" key versus "Selection from auto-suggest"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse,  there is a way to figure out whether a selection was made or the Enter key was pressed while showing selection on the map.

Below is the working code to implement this-

```js
require([

        "esri/map",
        "esri/dijit/Search",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/domReady!"

      ], function (Map, Search, on) {
         var map = new Map("map", {
            basemap: "gray",
            center: [-120.435, 46.159], // lon, lat
            zoom: 7
         });

         var search = new Search({
            map: map
         }, "search");
         search.startup();
         
        var isEnter= false;
        on(search.inputNode, "keypress", function(evt){
          isEnter = evt.keyCode == 13;
        });
        
        search.on("select-result", searchboxResult); 

         function searchboxResult(e)
           {
            alert(isEnter?"By Enter Selection": "By Suggestion Selection");
            // determine "Enter" key versus "Selection from auto-suggest"
          }

      });
```

```css
html,
      body,
      #map {
         height: 100%;
         width: 100%;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
      }
      #search {
         display: block;
         position: absolute;
         z-index: 2;
         top: 20px;
         left: 74px;
      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/themes/calcite/dijit/calcite.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/themes/calcite/esri/esri.css">

<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>

<body class="calcite">
   <div id="search"></div>
   <div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Comment: Nice "thinking out of the box". Wonder why I didn't think of that. +1 and accepted.